# Avoid parsing JSON subdocument using Gson

Tags: gson

Suppose having the following JSON document:

```js
{
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": { /* complex object here */
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm interested only in the `id` and `value` and want to have `popup` stored as a string, that I will store to database and parse later, when needed.

I tried to to parse it into this class, but I'm getting the error: *Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT*.

```java
class Object {
    @Expose String id;
    @Expose String value;
    @Expose String popup; 
}
```

Is this possible with Gson?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get JSONObject for popup key and convert it to string?

```
JSONObject posts=new JSONObject(json);
String popup=posts.getJSONObject("popup").toString();
```

Comment: My actual structure is more complex that my example. The `popup` object is, say, two levels deeper and root object has 20 properties. I'd like to parse into object automatically, but I'm not interested in some subdocument, though I want to keep it as String. I know I can do it manually, but I'm asking for an automatic way.

Comment: Ok then it is possible with GSON. If you save it as string and want to parse it later, you must create your models/classes that are following your hierarchy in JSON so Gson library could parse it so after you deserialize it woth gson just use getter methods to retrieve model you want.

Answer (score 0):

in Gson every JSON object is treated as a class which you will make to get your convenience classes to get the response, so that you can populate your object directly from the json string instead of doing the hustle of looping

I have written some test class that will help you get the ouput you are looking for and vice versa is possible.

> MenuItem.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MenuItem {

    @SerializedName("value")
    private String value;

    @SerializedName("onclick")
    private String onclick;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getOnclick() {
        return onclick;
    }

    public void setOnclick(String onclick) {
        this.onclick = onclick;
    }
}
```

> PopUp.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class PopUp {

    @SerializedName("menuitem")
    private ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems;

    public ArrayList<MenuItem> getMenuItems() {
        return menuItems;
    }

    public void setMenuItems(ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems) {
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }
}
```

> Response.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("value")
    private String value;

    @SerializedName("popup")
    private PopUp popup;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public PopUp getPopup() {
        return popup;
    }

    public void setPopup(PopUp popup) {
        this.popup = popup;
    }
}
```

No that we have our required classes we will run it to test if it works by following test code

> PopUpTestDrive.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class PopUpTestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.setOnclick("Onclick:_"+i);
            item.setValue("Value_"+i);

            menuItems.add(item);
        }

        PopUp popUp = new PopUp();
        popUp.setMenuItems(menuItems);

        Response response = new Response();
        response.setId("file");
        response.setValue("File");
        response.setPopup(popUp);

        String jsonResult = (new Gson()).toJson(response);
        System.out.println(""+jsonResult);

    }
}
```

> output

```
{
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {
        "value": "Value_0",
        "onclick": "Onclick:_0"
      },
      {
        "value": "Value_1",
        "onclick": "Onclick:_1"
      },
      {
        "value": "Value_2",
        "onclick": "Onclick:_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I was not asking for this. This is standard. In my case, the `popup` object is much larger and more complex. I was looking for a way to parse the top-level objects, and leave the complex inside for later. I solved it using the streaming API, but was curious, if such "partial" parsing is possible.

Comment: @Oliv, Kindly tell me how you did it, I would like to learn more on this, I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Have a look here: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming. You get events as tokens are parsed from the JSON stream. This way you need very little intermediate memory, if the data is large: you can insert into DB as you read. It is lot more complex to parse non-trivial objects this way.